# Keyboard appears on top of view where no user interaction should be allowed

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, keyboard

I have a window-based project with two `UITextField`s to take input from the user.
Both are in my view controller.

I have to parse stuff in the background, so I need something that blocks user interaction in the meanwhile.
I came across this [Cocoa With Love tutorial](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/showing-message-over-iphone-keyboard.html) to create a loading view on top of everything. It actually works pretty well, for the most part; it works when ever the text field resigns first responder.

There is one circumstance where it doesnt work, though. When I type something in the first text field and then select the second one, the loading screen will appear, but the keyboard is on top of it, so the user could type something. I want the loading screen to be on top of the keyboard.

In the tutorial, it says to call the keyboard's superview. What is the keyboard's superview?
I tried the following different snippets in my view controller, but nothing works.

```
loadingView = [LoadingView loadingViewInView:[self.view.window.subviews     objectAtIndex:0]];
```

---

```
loadingView = [LoadingView loadingViewInView:self.view];
```

---

```
loadingView = [LoadingView loadingViewInView:self.view.superview];
```

How can I make the loading screen appear on top of everything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to dismiss the keyboard when you show the loading view.  I don't think you're allowed to put anything on top of the keyboard.

That said, you could try using the root window as the view to see if that has any effect.

Comment: how can i access the root window in my viewcontroller ?

Comment: `self.view.window` or `[[UIApplication windows] objectAtIndex:0]`.  You could also try `lastObject` instead of `objectAtIndex:0` to see if there's another window on top (which is sometimes the case, as when displaying UIAlertViews).

Comment: I didn't think it would.  Only solution then is to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: alright now i have an other problem. I use the Editing did end Events to recognize when the user changes the textfield so I can start parsing. In the methode called I also start my loading view which should appear on top of everything so when the view appears i dissmiss the keyboard with resignResponder BUT of course when ever I do that I get an Editing did End event so I call this over and over again.......

Comment: You should probably ask another question to get that resolved.  If this question is resolved, accept the answer or write your own solution and accept that.